# Not able to retrieve mmap shared memory from child after fork()

Tags: c, multithreading, fork, mmap

Update: I was not able to get this working and took a different approach. The problem was, as @nos pointed out, not with this code but elsewhere. ArrayList allocates memory in its implementation, and that is not part of the shared memory we've allocated. Thank you for the responses.

Original question:

I have a single fork. My goal is to have the child populate a data structure(db - it is an ArrayList - external implementation) and then be able to read that data structure from the parent. Currently, the result is a seg fault because the data structure is empty in the parent process.

Here is the code:

```
    static ArrayList *db;
    pid_t child_pid, pid;
int child_status;

//set up shared memory structure
db = mmap(NULL, 20000, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, 
                MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);


child_pid = fork();
if(child_pid == 0) {

    //Some operations to initialize and populate db happen here. This works fine.


    //printAll(db, 1); //THIS would work. But I want to do this from the parent
    exit(0);

} else {
    //wait for child process to finish

        do {
            pid = wait(&child_status);

        } while(pid != child_pid);




    printAll(db, 1);//THIS IS WHERE IT SEGFAULTS, because db is not initialized - so it was never properly retrieved from mmap
    munmap(db, 20000); //fixed this



}
```

Comment: Why would you expect `printAll(ptr)` to be safe after you have munmap'd `ptr` ?

Comment: OS is ubuntu. Moved the munmap - didn't make a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 munmap(db, 20000);

 printAll(db, 1);//T//THIS IS WHERE IT SEGFAULTS,
```

That is not particularly surprising, you unmapped the memory on the line just above it.

Comment: Fixed - still same issue.

Comment: @llmar Then you have a bug elsewhere. The snippet of code you have will properly share the memory between the parent&child, you can verify this with a small sample, such as this, http://ideone.com/e0BXFq , and you can debug the code you have and manually inspect the memory.

Comment: You're right, that works just fine. I'm not sure where the bug is - perhaps my data structure is using another structure that is stored in a different memory location. I will look into this and post an update. Thanks.